# USB stick detected, but can't mount from fdisk, and doesn't show as sdb or sdX in terminal

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, usb-drive, gnome-disk-utility

I was using a 32GB usb memory to transfer files from an old laptop with windows xp to a more current pc with ubuntu 18.04 and while moving the files from the laptop to the usb stick I left the process neglected, when I returned to the laptop it had run out battery, i connected the laptop, i turn it on and the usb drive was no longer recognizable, i ejected it and passed to the pc with ubuntu, the sound that occurs when a removable media is connected sounded as usual, but it was not shown in files, i opened the disks utility and the device was detected, however it said No Media
[disk utility image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYO0M.png)

The output of `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c8:036a Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04ca:004b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID ffff:1201  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of `lsusb -v` Bus 001 Device 012 is (here is the usb stick):

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID ffff:1201  
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xffff 
  idProduct          0x1201 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

And it doesn't appear has "sdb" using `lsblk`, the port is ok as well as the power supply, I restart the laptop and PC, plug the usb into different ports and nothing change.

I would like to know if there is a way to recover the files and leave the usb dead, or delete what it contains but continue using it